# Count categorical variable ("yes") for each column

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

Can you please help me count how many YES answers are for each ingredient

I have a data set:

```
beef  beet_broth  beef_liver  beer  chicken
Yes      Yes         No       Yes    No
No       Yes         No       Yes    No
No       No          Yes      Yes    No
Yes      Yes         No       Yes    No
```

I would like to know the sum of YES in each column, if 0 then won't appear in results:

```
Beef - 2 
Beef_broth - 3
Beef_liver - 1
Beer - 4
```

I have data set: 384 columns, 57 691 rows

Comment: ok, but how to specify this group having answer "Yes"

aggregate(recipes, by=list(??) , FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)

*recipes is my data.frame

Answer (score 4):

We can use `colSums` to find the number of `"Yes"` values per column (because `TRUE` equates to 1 and `FALSE` to zero), then subset for the values greater than zero.

```
cs <- colSums(recipes == "Yes")
cs[cs > 0]
#    beef beet_broth beef_liver       beer 
#       2          3          1          4
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a more elegant way using `plyr`, but the following seems to be what you want:

```
> yesses = sapply(recipes,FUN = function(x){length(x[x=="Yes"])})
> yesses
      beef beet_broth beef_liver       beer    chicken 
         2          3          1          4          0 
> yesses[yesses > 0]
      beef beet_broth beef_liver       beer 
         2          3          1          4
```

**On Edit**. How it works: A dataframe is a list of column vectors. `sapply` takes a list and a function and applies the function across the list, returning the results as a vector. In the above I used an anonymous function which uses logical subsetting to take a column and extract the entries which equal "Yes". The length of the resulting subvector is the desired count. You could first define this function like thus:

```
countYes = function(v){length(v[v=="Yes"])}
```

And then define `yesses` as:

```
yesses = sapply(recipes,countYes)
```

which works exactly as above.

Disclaimer: I'm relatively new to R myself but have a lot of experience with Python. I typically think how I would solve a problem using a Python list comprehension and then paraphrase it in R, which typically involves some combination of subsetting and functions in the `apply` family. The resulting code works as desired, but might not be very idiomatic.

Comment: Hi John
thank you very much, this is indeed working :)
Could you please clarify me, where this function with length is coming from? I am a beginner in R language. 
Much appreciated